# How to merge 2 sql statements and get results at once

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I can't figure out how to merge these 2 queries and get result for them at once.

```
        $q1 = "SELECT q.id, q.content, a.id, a.content, a.addDT, acr.score 
            FROM questions_and_exercises q, `lesson-question` lq 
            LEFT JOIN answers a ON (a.uid=? AND a.qid=lq.qid)
            LEFT JOIN `answer_chk_results` acr ON (acr.aid=a.id)
            WHERE q.id=lq.qid AND lq.lid=?";
        $q2 ="SELECT q.id, q.content, a.id, a.content, a.addDT, acr.score
             FROM questions_and_exercises q,
             `questions from-to` qft
            LEFT JOIN answers a ON (a.uid=? AND a.qid=qft.qid)
            LEFT JOIN `answer_chk_results` acr ON (acr.aid=a.id)
            WHERE q.id=qft.qid AND qft.to_uid=?";
```

Suggetions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html), Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**UNION**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) for this matter.

However in this case, I don't think an `UNION` is even needed:

```
$q1 = "SELECT q.id, q.content, a.id, a.content, a.addDT, acr.score 
        FROM questions_and_exercises q, `lesson-question` lq 
        LEFT JOIN answers a
        ON a.qid=lq.qid
        LEFT JOIN `answer_chk_results` acr 
        ON acr.aid=a.id
        WHERE q.id=lq.qid AND a.uid = ? (lq.lid = ? OR qtf.to_uid = a.uid)";
```

It will smash together these 2 results into more rows.

```
$q1 = "SELECT q.id, q.content, a.id, a.content, a.addDT, acr.score 
        FROM questions_and_exercises q, `lesson-question` lq 
        LEFT JOIN answers a ON (a.uid=? AND a.qid=lq.qid)
        LEFT JOIN `answer_chk_results` acr ON (acr.aid=a.id)
        WHERE q.id=lq.qid AND lq.lid=?
        UNION # ALL
        SELECT q.id, q.content, a.id, a.content, a.addDT, acr.score
         FROM questions_and_exercises q,
         `questions from-to` qft
        LEFT JOIN answers a ON (a.uid=? AND a.qid=qft.qid)
        LEFT JOIN `answer_chk_results` acr ON (acr.aid=a.id)
        WHERE q.id=qft.qid AND qft.to_uid=?";
```

Either use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` depending on if you want to merge identical rows or not. An `UNION` requires the two `SELECT`s to have the same amount of columns, and will use the first `SELECT`s aliases.

You *could* easen up last query like this:

```
        SELECT q.id, q.content, a.id, a.content, a.addDT, acr.score
        FROM questions_and_exercises q,
        `questions from-to` qft
        LEFT JOIN answers a 
        ON a.qid=qft.qid
        LEFT JOIN `answer_chk_results` acr 
        ON acr.aid=a.id
        WHERE q.id=qft.qid AND qft.to_uid=? AND qtf.to_uid = a.uid
```

Basicly since it's the same value, it's enough to compare `to_uid` with `?`, then compare `to_uid` with `uid`. It's the same result as comparing them through `ON`.

Comment: Hey can you tell me what's `#` before `ALL` used for?

Comment: second query in qft.to_uid=? and a.uid=? `?` is same id. How can I optimize this query to send bir param for both `to_uid` and `a.uid`?

Comment: @epic_syntax Simply parsing the value twice is optimization enough for the MySQL query. @Mr. Alien It's just a comment I used to show that you can either have or skip `ALL` in `UNION`.

Comment: Is there any way to optimize this 2 queries? I looks too long. I mean, maybe there are some pieces unneeded, and maybe shortened

Comment: Probably just changing `WHERE q.id=lq.qid AND lq.lid=?` with `WHERE q.id=lq.qid AND a.uid = ? AND (lq.lid = ? OR qtf.to_uid = a.uid)` would be enough, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Use Union all

```
$q1 = "SELECT q.id, q.content, a.id, a.content, a.addDT, acr.score  
            FROM questions_and_exercises q, `lesson-question` lq  
            LEFT JOIN answers a ON (a.uid=? AND a.qid=lq.qid) 
            LEFT JOIN `answer_chk_results` acr ON (acr.aid=a.id) 
            WHERE q.id=lq.qid AND lq.lid=? union all
            SELECT q.id, q.content, a.id, a.content, a.addDT, acr.score 
             FROM questions_and_exercises q, 
             `questions from-to` qft 
            LEFT JOIN answers a ON (a.uid=? AND a.qid=qft.qid) 
            LEFT JOIN `answer_chk_results` acr ON (acr.aid=a.id) 
            WHERE q.id=qft.qid AND qft.to_uid=?";
```

Comment: second query in qft.to_uid=? and a.uid=? `?` is same id. How can I optimize this query to send bir param for both `to_uid` and `a.uid`?